# Does insertOoxml ignore provided tab stops?

Tags: office-js, openxml

I'm writing an Office Add-in, and trying to insert a paragraph using insertOoxml (because I need bold text and tab support, and HTML would do bold but not tabs, and text would maybe do tabs but not bold).

The problem I'm having is that I'm defining the custom tab stops for the paragraph, but they seem to be ignored by Word. The paragraph is inserted, it begins with a tab and ends with a tab just as requested, but the tabs' positions and character are simply ignored. The paragraph will use whatever tab stop definitions were there at the insertion point, or none if there were none.

```xml
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async (context) => {

    const xml = `
<pkg:package
    xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'>
    <pkg:part pkg:name='/_rels/.rels' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml' pkg:padding='512'>
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <Relationships
                xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'>
                <Relationship Id='rId1' Type='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' Target='word/document.xml'/>
            </Relationships>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name='/word/document.xml' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml'>
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <w:document
                xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' >
                <w:body>
                    <w:p>
                        <w:pPr>
                            <w:tabs>
                                <w:tab w:val="left" w:leader="underscore" w:pos="851"/>
                                <w:tab w:val="right" w:leader="underscore" w:pos="7880"/>
                            </w:tabs>
                        </w:pPr>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:rPr>
                                <w:color w:val="FFD966"/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:tab/>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t xml:space="preserve">Hello </w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:rPr>
                                <w:b/>
                            </w:rPr>
                            <w:t>World</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t>!</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:tab/>
                        </w:r>
                    </w:p>
                </w:body>
            </w:document>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
`
    context.document.body.insertOoxml(xml, Word.InsertLocation.replace)
    await context.sync()
  });
}
```

No error is shown.

To be clear, I'd rather define the tab stops as document defaults, and have none in the paragraphs, but I have found no way to do that (and it's a different issue anyway).

This is to run mostly on Word 2021, and I'm testing it on Word 2016. Is it an issue that has been solved?

Comment: Create a document manually that is styled the way you want. Add `.zip` to the end of the document filename. Then open the zip file and inspect the OOXML. Compare it with the OOXML you are insertng and see if there are any differences.

Comment: @RickKirkham that's how I got here. If you save the XML above to a file and open it in Word, the tab stops will be exactly as intended. It's when using `insertOoxml` that they seem to be ignored.

Comment: By "ignored" do you mean they have been removed from the OOXML or do you mean there are there but Word seems to ignore them when rendering the document?

Comment: @RickKirkham Word doesn't render them, doesn't show them in the tab stops dialog, and if I run getOoxml() they aren't there, while all the rest is. I've since seen that this happens in Word 2021 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. This is not much of an answer, but it seems to be the answer. Apprently, tab stops will only be taken into account by `insertOoxml` if at least two paragraphs are inserted. I've confirmed in Word 2016 and Word 2021.

So, the example in the question will work if an empty `<w:p/>` is added after the other paragraph.

For all I can see this is a bug and I don't know how it hasn't been caught yet, but maybe I'm missing something. Maybe most people aren't writing OOXML but just making changes to Word's own. I'll appreciate it if anyone can expand.

Comment: I think it is a bug. You should report it in the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues).